# django; Cannot upload image and form data is invalid

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django and I am practicing with it now. I am creating image uploading system, but I cannot upload image uisng form even though I can post and save data through admin. Here is my code.

`models.py`

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='item', max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1)
    description = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`forms.py`

```
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['title', 'image', 'price', 'description']
        widgets = {'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80})}
```

`views.py`

```
def sell_item(request):

    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = ItemForm()
    else:
        form = ItemForm(data=request.POST)

        if not form.is_valid():
            raise ValueError('invalid form')

        new_item = form.save(commit=False)
        new_item.user = request.user
        new_item.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('mainapp:index')
    return render(request, 'mainapp/sell.html', {'form': form})
```

here is html code of the part.

```
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">submit</button>
</form>
```

When I fill out the data and submit them, it raises ValueError.
form looks good so I guess there is a problem with how to save the image data or html code but I cannot understande how to fix this. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not [passing `request.FILES` to your form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads) when you initialise it. Pass it as follows:

```
form = ItemForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```